# Multiple Property Drawers for Attribute not work properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, attributes, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

I have 2 attributes:

- `IconBool`: adds color icon in front of the field, and have custom height using `GetPropertyHeight()`.
- `LockInInspector` only enable and disable with `EditorGUI.PropertyField`.

which work like this

```
        [LockInInspector]
        [SerializeField] bool b;

        [LockInInspector]
        [SerializeField] int i;

        [LockInInspector]
        [SerializeField] Vector3 v3;

        [LockInInspector]
        [SerializeField] string s = "string";

        [IconBool(iconPath)]
        [SerializeField] bool bb;

        [IconBool(iconPath)]
        [SerializeField] bool bbb;
```

[image]

but when I put 2 attributes together, seems not working properly

```
        [IconBool(iconPath)]
        [LockInInspector]
        [SerializeField] bool b1;

        [LockInInspector]
        [IconBool(iconPath)]
        [SerializeField] bool b2;

        [SerializeField] Vector2 vector2;
```

[image]

First bool with IconBool first not disabling gui,

second bool with LockInInspector not have proper height.

Here is my code

LockInInspector:

```
    [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(LockInInspectorAttribute))]
    public class LockInInspectorDrawer : PropertyDrawer
    {
        public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
        {
            GUI.enabled = false;
            EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property, label);
            GUI.enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

IconBool:

```
    [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(IconBoolAttribute))]
    public class IconBoolDrawer : PropertyDrawer
    {
        IconBoolAttribute iconBool;
        readonly float lineHeightScaler = 1.5f;

        bool setted;
        Color red;
        Color green;
        Texture2D icon;
        GUIContent content;
        Vector2 contentSize;

        public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
        {
            return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * lineHeightScaler;
        }
        public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
        {
            if (property.propertyType != SerializedPropertyType.Boolean)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Property with [IconBool] attribute must be type of 'bool'");
                base.OnGUI(position, property, label);
                return;
            }

            if (!setted)
            {
                iconBool = attribute as IconBoolAttribute;

                ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString("#FF7585", out red);
                ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString("#90EEC9", out green);
                icon = EditorGUIUtility.Load(iconBool.iconPath) as Texture2D;
                content = new GUIContent($"{label.text}");
                contentSize = EditorStyles.label.CalcSize(content);

                setted = true;
            }

            if (property.boolValue)
            {
                GUI.color = green;
            }
            else
            {
                GUI.color = red;
            }
            //DrawRect(position);
            EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);
            position.height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * lineHeightScaler;
            position.width = position.height;
            GUI.DrawTexture(position, icon);
            GUI.color = Color.white;

            if (iconBool.hasText)
            {
                position.x += position.height + 5;
                position.y += position.height - EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
                position.height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
                position.width = contentSize.x;
                GUI.Label(position, label.text, EditorStyles.label);
            }

            position.x = EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth - ((EditorGUI.indentLevel - 1) * 15) + 5;

            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
            bool b = GUI.Toggle(position, property.boolValue, "");
            if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
                property.boolValue = b;


            EditorGUI.EndProperty();
        }
        void DrawRect(Rect rect)
        {
            Vector3 tl = new Vector3(rect.xMin, rect.yMin, 0);
            Vector3 tr = new Vector3(rect.yMax, rect.yMin, 0);
            Vector3 bl = new Vector3(rect.xMin, rect.yMax, 0);
            Vector3 br = new Vector3(rect.yMax, rect.yMax, 0);
            Handles.DrawLine(tl, tr);
            Handles.DrawLine(bl, br);
            Handles.DrawLine(tl, bl);
            Handles.DrawLine(tr, br);

        }

    }
```

What I what is both attributes work even with different order or even work with more than 2 attributes.

Comment: Could you share the entire script content(s) .. in particular the `[CustomPropertyDrawer]` attribute lines would be essential here I guess

Comment: Also a heads-up: (you are not the first one trying to lock things in the Inspector and) this will not work for lists and arrays since here Unity applies the drawer only to each element of the list/array, not the array itself ;)

Comment: Related: https://forum.unity.com/threads/drawing-a-field-using-multiple-property-drawers.479377/